# how to display a value in a column in the list if the value is repeating show only one time using mysql & codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is my requirement, If the value in a column is repeating then show only one time and blank for the next value comes.

[image: this the first table]

[image: this is how to display]

this is an example.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: This is all about representation of your data. Nothing to do in MySQL side.

Comment: `Order by title` in query. Iterate the array. Put old title  in variable `$oldTitle` and check `$oldTitle!=$array['newTitle']`  if `true` print `$array['newTitle']` . Update `$oldTitle` everytime at the end of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Name</th>
 </tr>

<?php $value=null;
foreach($view as $key){
 echo "<tr>";
 if($key['title']==$value){
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
 else{
    echo "<td>".$key['title']."</td>";
    $value=$key['title'];
  }
  echo "<td>".$key['Name']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```